# Sharing a List across subsites and being able to use them on subsite workflows & lookups for new columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, site

Currently I have a Subsite named "AR". In this site I have a List. This List has the information for every single person responsibly for each task. This list is used for workflows on document libraries to send e-mails when certain triggers happen.

My goal: I would like to be able to use this list in every other subsite that would be created. If I have 5 total subsites I would only have to update the original list. Is this possible?

What I've already done: I've used this guide to bring over the list.

http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites

However I cannot use the column lookup as its not listed as a "list", nor can I pull any data for my workflows.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: online or on-prem? SharePoint designer workflows or flow? Do you need to refer to the person field via a lookup from another list, or just access it via workflow?

Comment: Online. SP Designer workflows. I need to refer to the fields via lookup. (See image added above for current workflow usage)